# How many elements does the compiler take from an array which is function argument?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, sizeof

I have heard that when using an array as a function argument, the compiler takes it as not actually an array but as a pointer to the 1st element of the array. So, when asking for size of A(int array) it should return size of pointer 4 (in bytes). But I am getting 8. What is the problem?

I am using CodeBlocks.

```
int SumOfElemets(int* A, int size){//       int* A  or  int A[]   ... it is the same!

    int i, sum = 0;
    printf("SOE - Size of A = %d, size of A[0] = %d\n", sizeof(A), sizeof(A[0]));

//here it should be 4 and 4 but i am getting 8 and 4

    for (i=0;i<size; i++){

        sum += A[i];    //A[i] is *(A+i)
    }
    return sum;
}


int main(){

    int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int size = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);    //size of the array
    int total = SumOfElemets(A, size);
    printf("Sum of elements = %d\n", total);
    printf("Main - Size of A = %d, size of A[0] = %d\n", sizeof(A), sizeof(A[0]));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `A` is a pointer, its size is 8. `A[0]` is an `int`, its size is 4. The `sizeof(A)` in `main` (of an array) is different from the `sizeof(A)` (of a pointer) in the function. Even if the argument is `int A[]` it is still a pointer. An array passed to a function decays to a pointer.

Comment: So the hardware where you execute this code use 64bit (8*8) memory address.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank u. i understand the difference. but the problem was that in tutorial the exact same code was returning 4 and 4 and that got me confused. xd (link if u want: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuegQmMdy8M    time: 1:15:31)

Comment: Because that was probably a 32-bit compiler, with 32-bit pointers. Yours obviously has 64-bit pointers.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah :Dd I get that now, thx a lot

Comment: If the tutorial says you should always get 4, you are better off finding another tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

> Hi I have heard that when using an array as a function argument
> compiler takes it as not actually an array but as a pointer to the 1st
> element of the array.

Firstly function parameters having array types are adjusted by the compiler to pointers to the array element types.

For example these function declarations

```
int SumOfElemets(int* A, int size);
int SumOfElemets(int A[], int size);
int SumOfElemets(int A[1], int size);
int SumOfElemets(int A[100], int size);
```

are equivalent and declare the same one function.

On the other hand, arrays used in expressions as for example argument expressions with rare exceptions are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements.

So these function calls

```
SumOfElemets(A, size);
SumOfElemets(&A[0], size);
SumOfElemets(A + 0, size);
```

are equivalent.

The size of pointer is implementation defined as by the way the size of an object of the type `int` though usually `sizeof( int )` or in the case of your code `sizeof( A[0] )` is equal to 4.

Pay attention to that expression with the `sizeof` operator has the type `size_t`. So you need to use the conversion specifier `%zu` to output the value of the expression instead of `%d`

```
printf("SOE - Size of A = %zu, size of A[0] = %zu\n", sizeof(A), sizeof(A[0]));
```

Comment: thx a lot, i was asking because i saw this in one tutorial and he was using the exact same code, but unlike me he was getting 4 and 4. That got me confused (link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zuegQmMdy8M    time 1:15:31)

Comment: `sizeof array` and `char x[] = "abc";` are not really rare, so it is misleading to say that arrays are converted to pointers “with rare exceptions”. Maybe “with a few exceptions”.

Answer (score 1):

The [`sizeof`](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.4) operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand.

When you call `sizeof(A)`, that means "what is the size of the pointer `A`?".
That is different from `sizeof(A[0])`, which means "what's the size of the *first element* of the array `A`?".

**The size of types is compiler-dependent**, and in C implementations with a 64-bit address space, `pointers` are typically 64 bits (eight 8-bit bytes) and `int` are often 32 bits, therefore:

- 8 bytes for `sizeof(A)`;
- 4 bytes for `sizeof(A[0])`.

(Clarified by [**Eric Postpischil**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil))

---

Check out the following examples:
Example with a **x64** (**64bit** address space) compiler:
https://godbolt.org/z/vYcWhvxsE 
Output:

```
Size of pointer to int (x64): 8
Size of integer (x64): 4
```

Example with a **x86** (**32bit** address space) compiler:
https://godbolt.org/z/68PTsM6db 
Output:

```
Size of pointer to int (x86): 4
Size of integer (x86): 4
```

Comment: You are correct to point out that the size of int can vary between compilers, but the size of pointers are also implementation defined, and is not always 8.

Comment: @MagnusReftel I thought of adding that part when I was writing the second one, I'm gonna fix it and leave an example

Comment: “x64 (64bit) compiler” and x86 (32bit) compiler” are not well defined terms. There are multiple features of a compiler that might be 32-bit or 64-bit (or other widths), including the width of `int`, the width of `long`, the width of a `void *`, the width of a pointer to a function, and more. I have used a compiler targeting the “64 bit” Intel x86-64 architecture that had 32-bit pointers. Coarse terms like “64-bit compiler” ought to be avoided especially when asserting that a 64-bit compiler has eight-byte pointers, since it is not a universally true statement.

Comment: **thx a lot**, but didnt you swap those examples? U r talking firstly about x64 and in the example there is x86...

Comment: @HonzaPíka yes, I mistakenly swapped the outputs of the examples (even though the links were ok)

Comment: @EricPostpischil you're right, maybe it would be more accurate to say that "integer *usually* are represented as 4 bytes by 64bit compilers"?

Comment: Again, I would avoid the term “64-bit compiler.” A good statement could be “In C implementations with a 64-bit address space, pointers are typically 64 bits (eight 8-bit bytes) and `int` is often 32 bits.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil thank you, I've edited the answer to add the clarification